# JSON encode and decode (string)numeric indexed array

Tags: php, arrays, json

So I just stumbled upon this issue with array conversion to JSON and back to array. I used the function to store the array in database.

Code:

```
$array = array(
    1 => 'first',
    '200'  => 'second'
);
$array = json_encode($array);
$array = json_decode($array);
$array = (array)$array;

echo "<pre>"; var_dump($array);
var_dump(array_key_exists(1, $array));
var_dump(array_key_exists(200, $array));
var_dump(array_key_exists('1', $array));
var_dump(array_key_exists('200', $array));
```

Output:

```
array(2) {
  ["1"]=>
  string(5) "first"
  ["200"]=>
  string(6) "second"
}
bool(false)
bool(false)
bool(false)
bool(false)
```

Any explanation? Solution? Thanks?

Comment: @PaulCrovella so, there's no workaround for this in previous version? I'm working on this ancient website and would mess things up if I update PHP version just for this. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of

`$array = json_encode($array);
$array = json_decode($array);
$array = (array)$array;`

you only need to add a parameter to convert to array in json_decode

`$encoded_array = json_encode($array);
$array = json_decode($encoded_array, true);`

See documentation about `json_decode()` in http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Comment: Like a glove! (not sure if im using the expression correctly). Thanks